# High Screen Resolution [4:3]

Tags: graphic-drivers, display, resolution, intel

### High Screen Resolution [1280x1024][4:3]

i search google and tried to use the screen resolution. above but i failed 
i am newbie to this operating system , usually on windows when update my Graphic Driver {intel} 1280x1024 appear , so how to use this screen resolution or update my VGA 
Currently screen resolution is [1024x768] it's very big for me

Comment: Go to settings > display and change the resolution. My laptop was 1600x900 (my full resolution) by default.I do not know why yours isn't